# How to copy into an array in flex without modifying its reference in an efficient way?

Tags: actionscript-3

How to copy into an array in flex without modifying its reference in an efficient way? Efficient way needed as the array I am working upon is huge.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you mean by 'reference' and 'copy'.

`var copyArr:Array = oldArr` would NOT copy, but copyArr would be same as oldArr in all respect (so much so that changing something in copyArr would change that in oldArr too).

While, OTOH,

```
for(var i:uint=0; i<oldArr.length; i++)
{
    newArr.push(item);
}
```

would copy each item's reference in oldArr into newArr. But, there is no way to optimize it further.

If you want a deep-copy, then you write oldArr into a ByteArray and then read it back into newArr.